# Hyper-V Server Cluster with Microsoft iSCSI Target Storage

Tags: windows-server-2008, hyper-v, iscsi, windows-storage-server

I Have a windows 2008 R2 Ent Server. I installed a Microsoft iSCSI Target 3.3 configured and everything was fine until one reboot. The iSCSI Service will not start.

You Can reproduct the error:

1   Install Windows Server 2008 R2 Ent. (64bit) 
2   Run Windows Update 
3   Run DCPROMO and make a new forest and new domain also
4   Download and install Microsoft iSCSI 3.3
5   Install one klient, join a domain and attache the storage
6   Check that everything are OK
7   Shutdown a klient
8   Restart a server.
9   enjoy your own error msg.

The log from event viewer:

```
Log Name: Application
Source: Application Error
Date: 2011.11.27. 17:40:12
Event ID: 1000
Task Category: (100)
Level: Error
Keywords: Classic
User: N/A
Computer: storage.demo.local
Description:
Faulting application name: WinTarget.exe, version: 6.1.7600.16561, time stamp: 0x4e8e0274
Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 6.1.7601.17514, time stamp: 0x4ce78f36
Exception code: 0x80000003
Fault offset: 0x0000000000017f32
Faulting process id: 0xcb4
Faulting application start time: 0x01ccad233b8b8a12
Faulting application path: c:\Program Files\Microsoft iSCSI Software Target\WinTarget.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\system32\KERNELBASE.dll
Report Id: 79785a1a-1916-11e1-aa26-b0487a82a2c2
```

I tried uninstalling the target service and reinstalling it, but upon reboot I still receive:

```
Log Name: System
Source: USER32
Date: 2011.11.27. 18:40:26
Event ID: 1076
Task Category: None
Level: Warning
Keywords: Classic
User: DEMO\**********
Computer: storage.demo.local
Description:
The reason supplied by user DEMO\******* for the last unexpected shutdown of this computer is: Other (Unplanned)
Reason Code: 0xa000000
Problem ID: 01
Bugcheck String: 
Comment:
```

Comment: If you seriously want help from other people you really need to put an ounce of effort into crafting a coherent and well formatted Question. You are the one asking for help, the onus is on you to give the perception that our efforts aren't being wasted.

Comment: Looks vaguely like the system is corrupted, maybe a partial service pack installation or something similar. Did you install all available Windows updates before installing the Target (the first time you installed the Target software)? Try running `sfc /scannow` and see what it finds?

Comment: The systems are upto dated, the windows Update sad that :),, if update is the reason than why worked it before, till restart ?

Comment: One +
I uninstalled the target, and install again .... no way, becouse every install process go to unexpected shut down :(

Comment: I did not ask if the system were up to date **now**. I asked if they were up to date **before you installed the Target software**. Did you run `sfc /scannow` yet?

Answer (score 1):

The problem appears to be that you are trying to install an iSCSI target onto a DC. Promoting a server to DC can mess with IP because you are effectively binding a NIC to domain services.  There are other things going on under the hood in terms of how the DC will set security levels for other NICs.  I'm not a AD expert I've just noticed things happen.  Installing any service or even multi-homing a DC is generally frowned upon.

Having said that, in a test environment I've installed services onto a DC and used the **iscsi initiator** on a DC, with a storage target elsewhere.  But I've never tried to make the DC a **storage target**, and I have to say that from a security point of view I can't see the rationale for doing this.  But if you are really set on doing it, why not try using another free Windows-based iSCSI target?